# How to keep state of seekbar on pause android?

Tags: android, media-player, state, seekbar

android developer

I have an application that play music from sd card using media player.
In this application, I have a seekbar to indicate the music that being play.
The seekbar run in thread, and updated while music is playing.

If a press the back button, the music is still playing as I want.
But if I click the application again, the seekbar is back to 0.
It means all instances are created the new one.

What I supposed to do, to save the instance of the media player when I press back button?
What kind of implementation that I should do at onPause and onResume?

Answer (score 1):

you have to save the state of your application and then restore it using `onRestoreInstanceState` when your application start again. see here [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)